# Unable to mount previously working drive

Tags: mount

Help, I've been banging on this for days. I re-install either 10.04 or 12.04 and Ubuntu boots fine. I pop off the cd drive and plut in the other hard drive (320gb/NTFS) and initially you can see the drive in Ubuntu but can't mount. Following the fstab and virtual drive instructions :

```
/dev/sdb    /mnt/D_Drive    auto    rw,auto,user,exec   0   0
```

I attempt to mount -a 
or

```
/etc# sudo mount -t ntfs  /dev/sdb /mnt/D_Drive
```

Here is what I see for disks/partitions

```
root@crunch005:/etc# sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 120.0 GB, 120034123776 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 14593 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000ac3

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1       13995   112412672   83  Linux
/dev/sda2           13995       14594     4805633    5  Extended
/dev/sda5           13995       14594     4805632   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/sdb: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x07147c7f

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb2            2937       38913   288985252+   5  Extended
/dev/sdb5            2937       38913   288985221    7  HPFS/NTFS
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ops - here is what I get when attempting to mount:

Comment: /etc# sudo mount -t ntfs  /dev/sdb /mnt/D_Drive
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sdb' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?

Comment: I would suggest installing testdisk and using that to recovery any drives

Comment: Does Windows recognize the drive? If it does, run `chkdsk /B /V` on it?

Answer (score 0):

You want to mount the NTFS partition not the whole disk.
Your mount command should therefore look like `sudo mount -t ntfs  /dev/sdb5 /mnt/D_Drive`.

Similarly correct fstab line is `/dev/sdb5    /mnt/D_Drive    auto    rw,auto,user,exec   0   0`
(just add a NTFS partition number to the device name part, which is 5 according to fdisk output).